# How I can mock A with B mock as constructor parameter?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking

How I can mock A with B mock as constructor parameter?

```
private B actionContext;
private A target;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    actionContext = mock(B.class);
    target = mock?
}

public class A {//...
    public A(B b){//...
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you testing class A or other class that uses A to call a B method?

Comment: @EdwinMiguel I am testing class A.

Comment: You don't need to mock the A class, just add the B mock in the A constructor

Comment: @EdwinMiguel, I need to mock some A methods in addition to B mock.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mockito annotation

```
@Mock
private B mockB;

@Spy
@InjectMocks
private A testObj = new A(mockB);
```

set up test behavior in setUp method...
when(mockB.method()).thenReturn();

Comment: As I see, new A(mockB) is not a mock, but I need it also mocked.

Comment: @ArthurDn from my understanding when if you are trying to test a class you don't want to mock that class - you want to mock its dependencies so you can test it in isolation

Comment: Agreed, but what if you method A.a uses method A.b and you want to write separate tests for them?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking - please explain. If A.a calls a method of the mocked class B? or if A.a calls a method of it's own class?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to mock `class A` methods you don't need to mock `class B`

mocking `class A` is enough

```
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    A mockedA = mock(A.class);
}
```

And if you want to use mocked methods of `class B` you can mock it separately

```
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    A mockedA = mock(A.class);
    B mockedB = mock(B.class);
}
```

also will suggest you to read [Mockito docs](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.3.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html) to understand mocking principles .